# calculation of angle between 3 points python

Tags: python

I want to make a code to calculate angle between 3 points.
I use the function and the function itself is no problem.
But, in my case, the lineA and lineB below are varialbes so I think trouble occurred because of this point.
Thank you in advance.

```
def dot(vA, vB):
    return vA[0]*vB[0]+vA[1]*vA[1]

def ang(lineA, lineB):
    vA = [(lineA[0][0]-lineA[1][0]), (lineA[0][1]-lineA[1][1])]
    vB = [(lineB[0][0]-lineB[1][0]), (lineB[0][1]-lineB[1][1])]
    dot_prod = dot(vA, vB)
    magA = dot(vA, vA)**0.5
    magB = dot(vB, vB)**0.5
    cos_ = dot_prod/magA/magB
    #angle = math.acos(dot_prod/magB/magA)
    angle = math.acos(cos_)
    ang_deg = math.degrees(angle)%360
    if ang_deg-180>=0:
        return 360 - ang_deg
    else:
        return ang_deg

an1=1
an2=1.5
an3=2
an4=2
an5=2.5
an6=0.5
angle1=ang(lineA=((an1,an2), (an5,an6)), lineB=((an1,an2), (an3,an4)))
```

Comment: what is the error and what kind of help are you looking for? what do you want exactly?

Comment: Sorry. The error is 'math domain error' in angle = math.acos(cos_). But, when I input coordinates directly into the lineA and lineB, it is no problem.

Comment: Can you tell us the values used when you get the error? I suspect the points are causing a division by 0 somewhere.

Comment: the values are in the code. an1~an6

Answer (score 0):

It is only a typo.

```
def dot(vA, vB):
    return vA[0]*vB[0]+vA[1]*vA[1]
                           # ^^^^^ should be vB[1]
```